# File explorer won't start

Tags: java, android

So I have been trying to create my own file-browser via [this manual](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/07/example-of-file-explorer-in-android.html)

And every time I start the app it crashes. My Log says this:

```
05-08 09:31:46.520 23657-23657/com.example.mrwhite.fileexplorer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mrwhite.fileexplorer, PID: 23657
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mrwhite.fileexplorer/com.example.mrwhite.fileexplorer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804)
```

Can someone help me solving this?

Comment: Did you add runtime permission for Read External Storage ?

Comment: Usually the process is,copy the error,paste it at google,open SO question,see your code then the answer,find the difference,fix it

Comment: its a NPE so first step would be check your objects or arrays or lists if they are initailized or not.

Comment: `File[] files = f.listFiles();`. After that add `if(files==null) return;`.

Comment: yes, the permissions are granted in my manifest

Comment: No. Not granted. Requested. But that is not enough for Android 6+. See first comment.

Comment: oh thanks that worked! But now it wont show my folders, why is that?

Comment: Probably explained in previous comments.  The `null` test is causing the app to **not crash** with an NPE when the OS won't let the app see the user's files (due to an app permissions issue ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and change some this get Dire method..

```
   private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }
    if (files.length!=0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                } else {
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions();
    } else {


        getDir(root);
    }

}
/**
 * this method request to permission asked.
 */

private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
    } else {
        Log.i("Error", "Requesting permission");
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }
    if (files.length!=0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                } else {
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}
/**
 * this method check permission and return current state of permission need.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i("Error", "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission was granted. Kick off the process of building and connecting
            // GoogleApiClient.
            getDir();//define path
        } else {
        }
    }

}
```

and i hope you add below permission into android manifest file..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and i make two method for check runttime permission in my code.

Comment: now i got connot resolve symbol"REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE"

Comment: it is local variable     private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

Comment: there is an argument missing also in the method onRequestPermissionsResult when calling getDir(..)

Comment: I mention comment pass your path.

Comment: Sry i was trying for hours... now it pretty much works thanks to your help!! :D Butif i want to open a file how would that be possible theres nothing happening when i click on a pdf. Like for an example i have to open xmls for my application